# Re-export all imports with changed type definition

Tags: node-modules, typescript-typings

We have a git submodule of React components written in poorly typed TS. It has a single `index` file, which re-exports everything like this:

```
export * from './blocks'
```

Then, in the main app, we use `import * as allBlocks from '../packages/blocks'` or `import {SomeBlock} ...`.

But now, I have added some type declarations to the mentioned index file, which, however, need to be imported separately to use.

> #### Is there a way to tell TS to re-export as the new type?
>
> *for example something like this:*
>
> ```
> export * from './blocks' as TheNewType
> ```

This is how the index file looks currently.

```
export * from './blocks' // I want to export all as different type

// all this is just for the types

import * as allBlocks from './blocks'

type AllBlocks = typeof allBlocks
type BlockNames = keyof AllBlocks

export type BlockComponents = {
  [key in BlockNames]: BlockComponent<ExtractComponentGenerics<AllBlocks[key]>>
}

type BlockComponent<P = {}> = React.ComponentType<P> & BlockComponentStatics<P>

/** This interface types some static properties used by our library, that are not normally present on React.ComponentType */
interface BlockComponentStatics<P = {}> {
  getInitialProps?(): P | Promise<P>;
  // ...
}


function assertIsBlocks(val: any): asserts val is BlockComponents {/*...*/}

assertIsBlocks(allBlocks)

export allBlocks // This unfortunatelly produces named export, which I don't want.
export default allBlocks // I don't want this neither. I want the * export.
```

Since this package doesn't come as a module, I am not sure if and how I can use Ambient module declaration or Module augmentation.

Comment: So you want to override types with the same (and then export the new ones) name or export the same with additional types?

Comment: @VRoxa Not sure if I understand you. I want to export the same javascript as in the first snippet, but with changed types so that it doesn't use the default type inference, but instead uses my mapped types.